# Subprocess behavior running from IDE (Thonny) vs service

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm attempting to run a shell script from python using this code:

```
subprocess.call('./update-script.sh', shell=True, cwd=temp_dir)
```

If I run my python code from the IDE (Thonny), it does exactly what it's supposed to do. 
But when the python script is started via a service on boot, it gets to this subprocess.call and the application exits without any error. All of my other controls work just fine.

Any idea what might be going on?
I'm using Python3, Thonny, on a RaspPi Zero.

Comment: Try running: `subprocess.call('ls; ./update-script.sh', shell=True, cwd=temp_dir)` and make sure the `cwd` of the subprocess is the same directory as the shell script

Comment: Alternatively - use the absolute path of the shell script i.e `subprocess.call('/var/tmp/update-script.sh', shell=True)`

Comment: @AK47 I just attempted both of your suggestions, still just dies silently.

Comment: use `subprocess.check_output` to see why it's failing

Comment: The paths in the call are relative, so it possible (very likely) the current working directory isn't the same as it is when you're using the IDE.

Comment: Have you checked your `script.sh` permissions? Can the Python script execute it?